Moving Applications in SCCM
new here but have been using the site a long time. I am trying to create a powershell script so i can automate the google chrome updates I do I am unable to get the application to create in the right folder.  And i am not able to move it to the right folder either. it keeps telling me that the folder is invalid.  the code I am using is
$App = get-cmapplication -name "Google Test_Test"
$FolderPath = "\3rd Party\Google Chrome\"
Move-CMObject -ObjectId $App.CI_ID -FolderPath $FolderPath

The path of where I want to put them in the SCCM console is correct according to the current object in the container\folder so I am at a bit of a loss.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
I have run the code and changed the path to other variations included the site code etc but still not working.

Please post the exact error message in full :)

According to the documentation, -FolderPath:

Specifies a destination folder path, in the following format: <site code>:\<object type>\folder\subfolder\subfolder.

So try that:
$App = Get-CMApplication 'Google Test_Test'
$SiteCode = 'SC1' # replace with your actual site code

$App |Move-CMObject -FolderPath "${SiteCode}:\Application\3rd Party\Google Chrome"


Sending you a virtual high 5.  That worked lovely.  Thank you very much.
